# Django access nested object field in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I `Django-Rest` have a class `User` that contain the field `first_name`, and a class `Account` that contain the fields `username` and `a_class_ref` that is a `one-to-one'` relation.

How it is possible in the serializer of `B` to do something like :

```
class AccountSerializer():
    class Meta:
        model= Account
        fields= [
          'username',
          'firstname` 
        ]
```

Account :

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='account',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    def username(self):
        return self.user.username <== this is the solution that I'm trying to avoid
```

And `User` is the extended `AbstractUser` from Django-rest-framework, that comes with a `first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)`

Thank you

Comment: you will need to create a serializer in order to display the information of a_class_ref, looks for nested serializer in the documentation

Comment: Yes but I'd like to do it a way that at the end, the json is not in "nested format", so it's transparent to the user

Comment: May you add the model's code? Also if instead of using those cryptic names you used the real ones it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare a custom field with the [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) attribute:

```
class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a_field = serializers.CharField(source='a_class_ref.a_field')

    class Meta:
        model= B
        fields= ['b_field', 'a_field']
```

**Edit**

Based on the models you posted, the following should work:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='account',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')
    firstname = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name')

    class Meta:
        model= Account
        fields= ['username', 'firstname']
```

Comment: It sounds like it is exactly what I was looking for, but I still have this exception : `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name firstname is not valid for model Account.`

(Account is `B`, and firstname is `a_field`)

Comment: I edited my original post, in `B`, `A` is a `one-to-one` relation field

Comment: @BorisLeMéec you can't directly access `a_fileld`. Note that I'm going via `a_class_ref`. What is the field name on `Account` that you use to reference the other model?

Comment: I wrote `firstname = serializers.CharField(source='user.firstname')` and `user` is the `one-to-one` related field in the `B` class, that refers to the `A` class

Comment: Are you sure it's `firstname` and not `first_name`? What does your `Account` model look like?

Comment: I changed `firstname` to `first_name` in the `source` attribute to match the one in `user` class, but nothing changed, the error is still about `Account`.
Account look like this :
`...
user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='account',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
...`

Comment: @BorisLeMéec Can you please paste all your real models and serializers? It is hard to debug without that information.

Comment: @BorisLeMéec Answer updated with what I think you should have.

Comment: That was probably a typo mistake, I just copy paste your code and it's working now thank you !